# Could not initialize class org.apache.hudi.common.bootstrap.index.HFileBootstrapIndex

Tags: apache-flink, apache-hudi

I'm trying to use Hudi with out Flink pipelines to publish data to S3 Object storage in parquet format. I am facing the below error while doing so:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hudi.common.bootstrap.index.HFileBootstrapIndex
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hudi.common.util.ReflectionUtils.getClass(ReflectionUtils.java:55)
    at org.apache.hudi.common.util.ReflectionUtils.loadClass(ReflectionUtils.java:79)
    at org.apache.hudi.common.bootstrap.index.BootstrapIndex.getBootstrapIndex(BootstrapIndex.java:163)
    at org.apache.hudi.common.table.view.AbstractTableFileSystemView.init(AbstractTableFileSystemView.java:118)
    at org.apache.hudi.common.table.view.HoodieTableFileSystemView.init(HoodieTableFileSystemView.java:113)
    at org.apache.hudi.common.table.view.HoodieTableFileSystemView.<init>(HoodieTableFileSystemView.java:107)
    at org.apache.hudi.common.table.view.FileSystemViewManager.createInMemoryFileSystemView(FileSystemViewManager.java:177)
    at org.apache.hudi.common.table.view.FileSystemViewManager.lambda$createViewManager$5fcdabfe$1(FileSystemViewManager.java:272)
    at org.apache.hudi.common.table.view.FileSystemViewManager.lambda$getFileSystemView$1(FileSystemViewManager.java:115)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hudi.common.table.view.FileSystemViewManager.getFileSystemView(FileSystemViewManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.hudi.table.HoodieTable.getSliceView(HoodieTable.java:320)
    at org.apache.hudi.sink.partitioner.profile.DeltaWriteProfile.getFileSystemView(DeltaWriteProfile.java:93)
    at org.apache.hudi.sink.partitioner.profile.WriteProfile.<init>(WriteProfile.java:120)
    at org.apache.hudi.sink.partitioner.profile.DeltaWriteProfile.<init>(DeltaWriteProfile.java:44)
    at org.apache.hudi.sink.partitioner.profile.WriteProfiles.getWriteProfile(WriteProfiles.java:75)
    at org.apache.hudi.sink.partitioner.profile.WriteProfiles.lambda$singleton$0(WriteProfiles.java:64)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hudi.sink.partitioner.profile.WriteProfiles.singleton(WriteProfiles.java:63)
    at org.apache.hudi.sink.partitioner.BucketAssigners.create(BucketAssigners.java:56)
    at org.apache.hudi.sink.partitioner.BucketAssignFunction.open(BucketAssignFunction.java:122)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:34)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.open(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:101)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.KeyedProcessOperator.open(KeyedProcessOperator.java:55)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(RegularOperatorChain.java:107)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreGates(StreamTask.java:734)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreInternal(StreamTask.java:709)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:675)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:952)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:921)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:745)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:562)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hudi.sink.partitioner.BucketAssignFunction.close(BucketAssignFunction.java:247)
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.closeFunction(FunctionUtils.java:41)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.close(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:115)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamOperatorWrapper.close(StreamOperatorWrapper.java:163)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.closeAllOperators(RegularOperatorChain.java:125)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.closeAllOperators(StreamTask.java:1043)
        at org.apache.flink.util.IOUtils.closeAll(IOUtils.java:255)
        at org.apache.flink.core.fs.AutoCloseableRegistry.doClose(AutoCloseableRegistry.java:72)
        at org.apache.flink.util.AbstractAutoCloseableRegistry.close(AbstractAutoCloseableRegistry.java:127)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.cleanUp(StreamTask.java:951)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.lambda$restoreAndInvoke$0(Task.java:934)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:952)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:934)
```

Here is the hoodie.properties created:

```
hoodie.compaction.payload.class=org.apache.hudi.common.model.EventTimeAvroPayload
hoodie.table.type=MERGE_ON_READ
hoodie.table.partition.fields=eventId,eventName
hoodie.table.cdc.enabled=false
hoodie.archivelog.folder=archived
hoodie.timeline.layout.version=1
hoodie.table.checksum=3942898242
hoodie.datasource.write.drop.partition.columns=false
hoodie.table.recordkey.fields=event_id,event_timestamp
hoodie.table.name=sink_table
hoodie.compaction.record.merger.strategy=eeb8d96f-b1e4-49fd-bbf8-28ac514178e5
hoodie.datasource.write.hive_style_partitioning=false
hoodie.table.keygenerator.class=org.apache.hudi.keygen.ComplexAvroKeyGenerator
hoodie.datasource.write.partitionpath.urlencode=false
hoodie.table.version=5
```

I tried to have hudi-flink1.16-bundle-0.13.1 in the classpath, but that was giving few `NoClassDefFound` errors. So added the required libraries independently. Can someone please help me on what I'm missing here? TIA.

Flink version:1.17.1
Hudi version: 0.13.1

Comment: Following this as I am running into similar issue

Comment: @Riddle - I updated the post with the solution that worked for me. You can give a try

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding `hudi-flink-bundle` to plugins, `flink_dir/plugins/hudi/<hudi-flink-jar>`. I removed the same from libraries.